# Video won't play on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, video, ffmpeg, codec

I have an app that places videos online, and cannot find a way to get iPhones to actually play them.

ffprobe says:

```
  merc@mercs-thinkpad:/disk/home/merc/Downloads$ ffprobe 5801005ff1861ba1729757fbffprobe version 2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 20160609
    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
    WARNING: library configuration mismatch
    avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
    libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
    libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
    libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
    libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
    libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
    libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
    libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
    libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
    libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
  Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '5801005ff1861ba1729757fb':
    Metadata:
      major_brand     : isom
      minor_version   : 512
      compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
      encoder         : Lavf57.50.100
    Duration: 00:00:12.37, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 993 kb/s
      Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 928 kb/s, 29.83 fps, 29.83 tbr, 11456 tbn, 59.67 tbc (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
      Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 70 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

The video is [here](http://www.wonder-app.com/f/videos/5801005ff1861ba1729757fb)

The file was created using ffmpeg from within the app.

Is this a codec problem? What shall I do to make sure iPhones can actually play them?

Comment: It could be something as simple as the MOOV atom not being in front: add `-movflags +faststart` to ffmpeg. It may also be the video stream profile, although it shouldn't be an issue nowadays. Add `-profile:v main` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my... amazingly, it was the file name! Even though the mime type is set, if the file name is not `.mp4`, the file won't be treated as a movie file!

(Which is amazing to think about, if you know Apple's history...)